# Is it possible to use INDEX and MATCH with multiple criteria with OR statement?

Tags: excel, indexing

I am trying to use multiple range criteria with an OR() option on the second criteria in the match() function. If I were to use a third criteria it would be inclusive and skip the values I am trying to locate.

Have this currently:

```
=CELL("row",INDEX($D$69:$I$215,MATCH(1,(E30=E69:E215)*("Buy"=G69:G215),0),2))
```

**Is there a way to get this to work? **

```
=MATCH(1,(E30=INDIRECT("E"  & C30 & ":E" & C27)* **OR( ("Buy"=INDIRECT("G"&C30&":G"&C27)),("Reinvestment"=INDIRECT("G"&C30&":G"&C27))**)),0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one, avoid the use of `CELL` as it is volatile.  You can simple do:

```
=MATCH(1,(E30=E69:E215)*("Buy"=G69:G215),0)+MIN(ROW(E69:E215))-1
```

Two, to do `OR` in an array formula one can use `+` and replace the INDIRECT, which is also volatile with INDEX

```
=MATCH(1,(E30=INDEX(E:E,C30):INDEX(E:E,C27))*(("Buy"=INDEX(G:G,C30):INDEX(G:G,C27))+("Reinvestment"=INDEX(G:G,C30):INDEX(G:G,C27))),0)+C30-1
```

Depending on One's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

One can also use AGGREGATE:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(INDEX(E:E,C30):INDEX(E:E,C27))/((E30=INDEX(E:E,C30):INDEX(E:E,C27))*(("Buy"=INDEX(G:G,C30):INDEX(G:G,C27))+("Reinvestment"=INDEX(G:G,C30):INDEX(G:G,C27)))),1)
```

Which does not need the CSE entry.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to simplify the first function you provided and alter the ranges with a helper column (using the indirect function) to pull the data I needed. Was able to avoid use of the second match lookup.

Comment: @AlexHernandez as stated INDIRECT is Volatile and should be avoided if possible.  Too many will slow down the interaction on excel.

Comment: Got it, I replaced the use of indirect with the Aggregate function you provided and it works well. The use the unbounded E:E range in INDEX(E:E,C30) makes the dragging of rows slightly slower. I deleted most of the excess rows in sheet. Is there a way to bound these ranges -- instead of E:E --> i.e. E75:E208?

Comment: It is not the INDEX that is slowing it down but the use of array formula, that is slowing it down.